# Copy tables from one database to the other in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, copy, postgresql-9.1

I have a number of tables in a database in the server side in PostgreSQL. I want to have them all in another database. Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195125/copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another-in-postgres

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy a table from one database to another in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195125/copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another-in-postgres)

Answer (score 1):

Use PostgreSQL `pg_dump` utility with `-t table` option to define tables that should be dumped and restore them in a another database. For more information see PostgreSQL [pg_dump documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)