# Specify dblink column definition list from a local existing type

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

I am using dblink to move certain data between databases. Everything is save and sound but I am wondering if there is a more convenient way to define the column definition list of a dblink query result. I can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dblink('dbname=remote', 'select * from test')
AS t1(id integer, data text);
```

The tables I'm interacting with have the same schema definition in both databases (remote & local). I was thinking of something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM dblink('dbname=remote', 'select * from test')
AS t1 LIKE public.test;
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM dblink('dbname=remote', 'select * from test')
AS t1::public.test;
```

The column definition list tends to become quite long. Is there something I may have overlooked?

EDIT:

As this has been a problem for me before I created a small function as a work-around.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dblink_star_func(_conn text, _schema_name text, _table_name text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
VOLATILE STRICT
AS $function$
    DECLARE       
        _dblink_schema text;
        _cols          text; 
        _q             text;
        _func_name     text := format('star_%s', $3);
        _func          text;        
    BEGIN
        SELECT nspname INTO _dblink_schema
        FROM pg_namespace n, pg_extension e
        WHERE e.extname = 'dblink' AND e.extnamespace = n.oid;

        SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(column_name || ' ' || udt_name), ', ') INTO _cols
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = $2 AND table_name = $3;

        _q := format('SELECT * FROM %I.dblink(%L, %L) AS remote (%s)',
            _dblink_schema,
            _conn,
            format('SELECT * FROM %I.%I', $2, $3),
            _cols
        );

        _func := $_func$
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %s()
            RETURNS SETOF %I.%I
            LANGUAGE SQL
            VOLATILE STRICT
            AS $$ %s; $$
        $_func$;

        EXECUTE format(_func, _func_name, $2, $3, _q);

        RETURN _func_name;
    END;
$function$;
```

This function creates and yields a function that wraps the dblink call. It's certainly not meant for heavy lifting but convenience.It would be nice if it turns out it's not necessary at all.

```
> select dblink_star_func('dbname=ben', 'public', 'test');
┌──────────────────┐
│ dblink_star_func │
├──────────────────┤
│ star_test        │
└──────────────────┘
(1 row)

> select * from star_test() where data = 'success';
┌────┬─────────┐
│ id │  data   │
├────┼─────────┤
│  1 │ success │
└────┴─────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: I need your help. I'm trying to do what you initially asked but I'm can't find my way...

Comment: I'm strugling to make a version of your awesome code without intermediary function (`dblink_star_func`), to being able to query `select * from select_remote('dbname=ben', 'public', 'test') where data = 'success';` straight away. Could you have a look at my question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691511/postgresql-error-structure-of-query-does-not-match-function-result-type-using ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to make sure that your types are always in sync but this should work:

```
SELECT (t1::test).* 
  FROM dblink('dbname=remote', 'select * from test') AS t1;
```

The key is that often you need parentheses to ensure that the parser knows you are dealing with tuples.

For example this works for me:

```
 CREATE TABLE test (id int, test bool);
 select (t1::test).* from (select 1, true) t1;
```

But this throws a syntax error:

```
 select t1::test.* from (select 1, true) t1;
```

Comment: It doesn't work in `dblink` (Postgres 9.1). Throws the error `a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`

Comment: @ADTC Funny thing I came here because change from `dblink` function to `dblink_connect` and now isnt working.

Comment: See the solution of @Rémy Baron below. That works in Postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 17):

Try something like this :

```
select (rec).* from dblink('dbname=...','select myalias from foreign_table
  myalias') t1 (rec local_type)
```

Example (get tables stats from other database) :

```
select (rec).* from dblink('dbname=foreignDb','select t1 from
  pg_stat_all_tables t1') t2 (rec pg_stat_all_tables)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--You can make column names of table as a string and then apply it in your dblink.

Do $do$

Declare column_list text;

Begin

column_list := (Select array_to_string(Array(Select concat(column_name,' ',data_type) from information_schema.columns where table_name='type_a1'),','));

Execute format ($$ Insert into type_a1 Select * from dblink('host=localhost user=postgres password=1234 dbname=Test','Select * from type_b1')as linktable(%s);$$,column_list);

end;

$do$
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).