# How to restore specific data from previous backup on Postgres Heroku? (Eg. Accidentally deleted rows)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ngrok

Here's the situation : With Heroku & Postgres, you can have automatically generated backups dump file. **But what can you do with it?**

1. Dump it on your database, if you want to fully go back to the backup state
2. Dump it locally to "have a look", or to use production data in development environment
3. Set back specific rows of your database in a previous state (eg. restore accidentally deleted rows)

I found myself so much **struggling** about latter point that I wanted to share how I have done it.

**How to restore specific data from previous backup on Postgres Heroku?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Summary / TL;DR

In 3 steps you'll be able to execute very simply:

```
INSERT INTO production_db.table_name
SELECT * FROM backup_db.table_name -- backup_db being remote
```

First install the backup locally, second get a SQL script, third open your localhost to the outside world with **[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)**.

### Let's go?

#### 1. Download your dump file on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) and dump it somewhere:

- You can do that on a remote database if you have some servers available. But if like me you don't want to provision another production database on Heroku or somewhere else, locally will totally do.
- I like to use [PGAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) (available on Linux, Mac and Windows), but using command line and `psql` will also do (by reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line) by example)
- In PGAdmin, you'd do `Create a database`. Then right click on it and use the `restore` function. Select your dump file, click `Restore` and you're all set : **your backup data is available locally!** Good job!

#### 2. Access it from your remote database

I wanted to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM backup_db.table_name
-- So I could then do
INSERT INTO production_db.table_name
SELECT * FROM backup_db.table_name
```

And I would be all set. Super easy, right? Pretty obvious? This must have been done hundreds of times already. Well, no!

There is a utility called `db_link` in Postgres 9.1+, but it is pretty constraining as the following syntax applies:

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM db_link('host=localhost dbname=backup-28-08', 'SELECT fname, lname FROM users') AS remote (varchar255 fname varchar255 lname)
```

Every column name needs to be repeated twice including its type. Pretty heavy, we are far from the simple `SELECT * FROM backup_db.table_name`

So the idea here is to use the `information_schema` table content, which describes each table with its column names, its types etc. I found this question on SO: [Specify dblink column definition list from a local existing type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317216/specify-dblink-column-definition-list-from-a-local-existing-type) which helped me **a lot** (Thanks [bentrm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152783/bentrm)).

But its solution was a two steps process, first generating a function, then querying it:

```
SELECT dblink_star_func('dbname=ben', 'public', 'test');
SELECT * FROM star_test() WHERE data = 'success';
```

And I was still aiming at a 1 liner. After some little pain (not being a SQL Guru), here is the Gist : [https://gist.github.com/augnustin/d30973ea8b5bf0067841](https://gist.github.com/d30973ea8b5bf0067841)

I now can do:

```
SELECT * FROM remote_db(NULL::users) -- (Still not 100% about why I need the NULL::)
-- And also
INSERT INTO users
SELECT * FROM remote_db(NULL::users)
```

Awesome, right?

#### 3. Access localhost remotely

If your remote database is already available from the internet (=has an IP address, a domain name Eg. for Heroku it will look like: `ec2-54-217-229-169.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5672/df68cfpbufjd9p`) **you can skip this step**. But if you use your local database, you need to make it available from the outside world (so that the Heroku database can access it).

For this, I use the **wonderful [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)**.

Once installed I only need to enter the following command:

```
ngrok -proto=tcp 5432 #5432 being the default port for Postgresql. (Adapt if necessary)
                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Tunnel Status                 online                                                                                                                                                                
Version                       1.7/1.6                                                                                                                                                               
Forwarding                    tcp://ngrok.com:51727 -> 127.0.0.1:5432                                                                                                                               
Web Interface                 127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                                                                        
# Conn                        0                                                                                                                                                                     
Avg Conn Time                 0.00ms
```

And you'd only need to plug `db_link` (in the gist) to `host=ngrock.com port=51727` and you are **good to go**!

#### 4. Going further

There are many possible improvements to this. Here are some I see already:

- Considering the script as a default feature to `db_link` function
- Being more error-proof if database structures are different in backup and production
- Making comparison tool between database results and backup results (to only return diffing lines)
- Handle simple joins
- And even further would be to have an application level adapter (Eg. ActiveRecord in Rails) that could allow manipulation of backend objects instead of raw SQL like now

Hope I was clear! Please ask for more details otherwise

Comment: I noticed your Gist doesn't seem to exist anymore – do you have a mirror anywhere?

Comment: Answering my own question: aug-riedinger seems to have changed his Github username to augnustin, so the new URL is https://gist.github.com/augnustin/d30973ea8b5bf0067841.

Comment: Indeed. Good catch.