# psql syntax error, possibly on '-', when importing a dump

Tags: database, postgresql, syntax, dump, psql

(Using postgres 9.4beta2)

I have a dump that I want to import. I have done this with the 'psql' command, as elsewhere it is noted that this is required when using COPY FROM stdin:

```
psql publishing < publishing.dump.20150211160001
```

I get this syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "fbc61bc4"
LINE 1: fbc61bc4-2875-4a3a-8dec-91c8d8b60bcc root
```

The offending line in the dump file is the one after the COPY statement, here are both those lines together:

```
COPY content_fragment (id, content, name, content_item_id, entity_version) FROM stdin;
fbc61bc4-2875-4a3a-8dec-91c8dcontent    Content for root        content fbc61bc4-2875-4a3a-8dec-91c8d8b60bcc    0
```

The items in the data appear to be tab separated. I am wondering given that the error message says at or near "fbc61bc4", but the full string is "fbc61bc4-2875-4a3a-8dec-91c8dcontent", is psql not liking the '-' character?

Comment: beta2, why? Use at least a production ready version, beta2 had some serious bugs. And there is a difference in version for psql (client) and the database (server), please check both.

Comment: ok, I don't know how or why I ended up with beta2, but I will address that and report back...

Comment: I installed version 9.3.6 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error happens when the `COPY` itself fails because the table doesn't exist, or one of the mentioned columns doesn't, or the user lacks the permission to write into it, etc...

As `COPY` fails, the SQL interpreter continues to the next line and interpret it as if was an SQL statement, although it's actually data meant to be fed to `COPY`. Generally this leads to a syntax error,  preceded by the error telling why the `COPY` failed (and often followed by tons of errors if there are many lines of data).

See another question: [psql invalid command \N while restore sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427689/psql-invalid-command-n-while-restore-sql), which shares the same root cause and has some useful comments.

Comment: Thanks. The file was created with pg_dump, and the admin tells me he successfully manged to re-import a file (not necessarily this one) today, on another box. I'll check this out carefully tomorrow when I'm back at work.