# Postgresql table backup restoration

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a database which contains 50 tables (5 schemas, 5 tablespaces). And tried to take a backup of few tables (each table in different tablespace) using following command.

```
$psql -U my_db_user my_db_name -t my_table_1 -t my_table_2 -t my_table_3 > ttables.sql
```

Above command is working fine to take the *sql backup. But the table column value is having null values. While restoring the the dump using the following command getting some error due to null (`\N`) values which is in backup file (ttables.sql).

```
$cat ttables.sql | psql -d new_db -U new_db_user
```

Is there any way to avoid \N characters in backup dump file? or Any wrong with backup / restore command which I have used?

(Postgres version 9.1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [psql invalid command \N while restore sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427689/psql-invalid-command-n-while-restore-sql)

Comment: have verified that too, didn't work.

Comment: The first command will not take a backup. Did you mean to write `pg_dump` instead of `psql`?

Comment: yes, I need to take pg_dump of few tables and i have used pg_dump --host host_name --port port_id --username "user_name"  --format custom --verbose --file "/home/user/tbl_bkp.backup" --table "s1.tbl1" --table "s2.tbl2" --table "s2.tbl1" "db_name". seems command executed successfully. But while doing pg_restore with the following command, pg_restore --host host_name--port port_id --username "user_name" --dbname "new_db_name" --role "role_name" --schema public --verbose "/home/user/tbl_bkp.backup" not getting the expected output. showing constraint related error. so that, I have tried psql.