# Copy data from one database table to another database table in Postgrex query

Tags: postgresql

I am using `COPY public.source TO STDOUT;` It is copying table **source** from database **foo** and sending it to `psql shell`.

```
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   0   3
4   1   4
5   2   0
6   0   1
7   1   2
8   2   3
9   0   4
10  1   0
```

I want to copy all records from the same table `source` of database `foo` to table **dest** in database **bar**. Any idea how can I do it with query like `COPY public.source TO <missing solution to copy data into bar.public.dest>;`

Comment: I think it's better to do this in the shell and not with sql commands, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195125/copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another-in-postgres.

Comment: I am also to remove [tag:elixir] tag since the question has nothing to do with [tag:elixir].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answering the particular question about using `COPY`.

According to the documentation on PostgresSQL [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html),

> `COPY` — copy data between a file and a table

which roughly means you are to do this in two steps: copy the existing data from source DB to file/stdin and then copy from file/stdin to destination DB.