# Copy table with partitions from one database to another in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195125/copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another-in-postgres) shows how to copy a table from one database to another, where a similar table already exists:

```
pg_dump -a -t my_table my_db | psql target_db
```

However, this `pg_dump` only works on either non-partitioned table or a partition itself. I have many partitions in the two databases:

```
table_1_part_1
table_1_part_2
...
table_1_part_n
...
table_k_part_m
```

So, using `pg_dump`, I have to do that for each partition.

What is a good solution for efficient copying in this case? Assuming that all partitions exist in both databases. If there is SQL query, I can use it in a Python script.

Comment: If you can use the [dblink module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) and call a stored procedure from your Python script, then you can create a plpgsql procedure with a loop see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same need to copy a partitioned table from one postgres server to another (essentially I had to restore a dropped table)

As mentioned by @Edouard, dblink does help to get this done. I came across the same suggestion in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195125/copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another-in-postgres) contributed by @tinychen & @SebaGra.

Here is how the query will look:

```
insert into destination_db.table 
select * from
dblink('host=host_adress dbname=db_name user=user_name
password=password', 'select * from source_db.table') as t1(column1
datatype, column2 datatype, ....columnN datatype)
```

In my requirement there were close to 100 partitions with huge data, and hence the server request timed out after 2 hours & had to do it partition by partition.

But, I'm sure it can handle moderate volume easily.

If it was helpful, do consider giving a thumbs up!

Thanks,
Sanket

Answer (score 1):

pg_dump for PostgreSQL 16 seems to support this by using the option `--table-and-children=pattern` instead of `-t`:

> This is the same as the -t/--table option, except that it also
> includes any partitions or inheritance child tables of the table(s)
> matching the pattern.

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h HOST --table-and-children=schema.table DB_NAME > OUTPUT_FILE
```